# Libgdx spawn batch Texture in a if

Tags: java, libgdx

I want to spawn a Texture in a if question. But it is not spawning. Here is my code

```
if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) 
        {
            clicks ++;
            System.out.println(clicks);
            
            if (clicks == 50) 
            {
                batch.begin();
                batch.draw(spider, 100, 100);
                batch.end();
                System.out.println("you have 50");`
            }
```

In the log I see the text you have 50. But nothing spawns.

Greetings
Marcel1510

Nothing I dont know what i can do.

Comment: please add a [mre], it is unclear what `batch` is, and with the small code snipped you provided, it is not possible to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should move your if statement in `init()` method between batch begin and end methods. Like that:

```java
private void init(){
    ...

    batch.begin();

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyJustPressed(Input.Keys.SPACE)) {
        clicks ++;
        System.out.println(clicks);
        if (clicks == 50) {
            batch.draw(spider, 100, 100)
            System.out.println("you have 50");`
        }
        ...
    }

    ...

    batch.end();
}
```